# Meaning of "Integrated Matrix"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Among the steps that the agency has already taken, the FDA established the Therapeutic Biologics and Biosimilars Staff (TBBS) under the Office of New Drugs (OND) in the Center for Drug Evaluation and Research (CDER) to support consistent review and policy development efforts for biosimilar and interchangeable product development and approval. TBBS coordinates with other offices and divisions in CDER through an **integrated matrix** to manage the development and approval of biosimilar and interchangeable products. [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm613761.pdf)

Hi, I searched for "an integrated matrix" but I have no idea what it means.

Longman says

> 2 a situation from which a person or society can grow and develop
>    
>
> 3 a living part in which something is formed or develops, such as the substance from which your fingernails grow [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/matrix)

But still, I am not sure what it means exactly.

Comment: I think it means they took the Blue Pill, not the Red... & spend all week writing these press releases in the hope Neo will rescue them from the interminable boredom...

Comment: http://www.businessmate.org/Article.php?ArtikelId=186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is an imprecise use of the word "matrix".

"Integrated" suggest many things brought together to form one whole.

"Matrix" suggests a structure with many parts.

So the many offices and divisions of CDER and the TBBS work together as a whole. It reads like "marketing speak" or someone trying to use impressive words, without really knowing what they mean.

Matrix is an interesting example of how a word can change meaning. From "mother" to "pregnant animal" to "womb" to "medium in which something develops", to "grid of cells" to "table of numbers". It shows how the etymology of a word is often distantly related to the current meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they made that word up. A Google search didn't bring up any usages of the term *integrated matrix* for me either. Maybe a specialised sociology SE will understand.